# Python @property equivalent in Dart?

Tags: dart

Python has the possibility to have a method be accessed like a property with the decorator `@property`. Does Dart have anything like this?

```python
class Test():
    @property
    def example():
        return "This isn't really a property"

a = new Test()
print a.example
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The notion of [*getters*](http://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/contents/ch02.html#classes-getters-and-setters) looks similar :

```dart
class Test {
  String get example {
    return "This isn't really a property";
  }
}

main() {
  var a = new Test();
  print(a.example);
}
```